# Toolbar title changes on rotation on device to entered text in an EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-toolbar

I have an `editText` directly under my `Toolbar`. But when my device rotates, the Toolbar's title, (set by XML) changes to the `editText`'s current text.

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/newOccasion"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/titleET"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_title"
    android:hint="@string/titleET"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/titleET"
    android:nextFocusUp="@+id/titleET"
    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
    android:paddingStart="5dp"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:theme="@style/inputColors"
    android:lines="1"
    android:maxLength="35"/>
```

**FULL XML HERE:** http://pastebin.com/JBeAkVqY

Comment: Is this the entirely of the layout file?

Comment: Please share your java code

Comment: I don't have ANYTHING in my Java

Comment: Wait a sec... I forgot to `setSupportActionBar`

Comment: Nevermind, still didn't help.

Comment: @Shaishav no, it isn't

Comment: Well, can you share the other part then?

Comment: @Shaishav Ok, I will

Comment: Tried your code out, works fine for me. There must be something else you're not showing us in your application that's causing this.

Comment: @TheHungryAndroider there's only one thing I didn't show to avoid confusing: I replaced my custom EditText Library *(Rey's Material Library)* with `EditText`. Should've mentioned this

Comment: I'm also using an API 17 devic

Comment: If you're using Instant Run, then try completely uninstalling the app manually and reinstall. This might be a bug introduced by it.

Comment: @Shaishav I am using instant run... I'll see if I can do it.

Comment: Nope, not the problem @Shaishav

Comment: Turns out it's not only the toolbar, but all other editTexts too. When I rotate the screen, all the other editTexts get mixed up... This is weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Override these methods in your activity:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //do nothing
}
```

It worked perfectly. These restore your previous texts to the way they were when you do something such as rotating your device.