# Android - App bar action buttons disappearing when device orientated landscape

Tags: android, android-layout

I've set my app so it changes to a different layout when the device is orientated, which works fine but now my action buttons are not being displayed. Do I need to create a new app bar xml file for the landscape orientation? Here is my code, appreciate any help.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

        if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90 || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270) {

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_landscape);
        }

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    return true;

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

menu_main.xml - I want this to be used in both landscape and portrait orientations, meaning I want the same action buttons on both.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.james.task02b.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_delete"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/action_delete"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

activity_main_landscape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.james.task02b.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1">



        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:text="This is the landscape layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:id="@+id/textView2" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: are you checking this on an emulator or an actual device?

Comment: @EmdadHossain emulator, does this make a difference?

Comment: See this to stop recreating your activity: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38706635/6908226